# Referencing cell in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, offset

I can write the correct formula in Excel, but because I have so many `IF` statements, I have to put it into VBA. The formula in Excel is supposed to return a value from another worksheet ("Sheet2") based on a value (F5) selected on "Sheet1". Here is part of the Excel formula that was created (there are many more `IF` Statements):

```
IF($F$5="AOM",
   OFFSET('Sheet2'!B3,'Sheet2'!$B$1,1,1,1),
   IF($F$5 = "Mid Adj",
      OFFSET('Sheet2'!B3,'Sheet2'!$B$1,6,1,1),
      ""
     )
  )
```

Here is the *If Statement* part of the VBA I've created:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim dummyVar As String

If Target = Range("F5") Then

    If Range("F5").Text = "AOM" Then
        dummyVar = ProcAOM()

    ElseIf Range("F5").Text = "Mid Adj" Then
        dummyVar = ProcML()
```

For the Proc, I'm not sure how to set up the Offset formula that references another worksheet.

Comment: Should consider using VBA code `Select Case Range("F5").Text: Case "AOM": dummyVar = ProcAOM(): Case "Mid Adj": dummyVar = ProcML(): Case Else: dummyVar = "Unknown Case": End Select`

Comment: If your conditions only differ by offset value, do this: `=OFFSET('Sheet2'!B3, 'Sheet2'!$B$1, CHOOSE(MATCH($F$5, {"AOM", "Mid Adj", "Others"}, 0), 1, 6, 42), 1, 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand you are trying to achieve, this will be just for 1 cell? If so, you don't have to care about Worksheet_Change.

You can create a User Defined Function (UDF) for this purpose. Say `BigIF` with assumptions:

- The Reference Cell does not change (B3 of Sheet2)
- Row Offset is defined in a fixed cell (B1 of Sheet2)
- Column Offset is determined in the code
- Returns the value of the range offset from Reference Cell

Paste below code into a module and use it in worksheet just like a formula, but referencing the F5 of Sheet1 (doing this forces Excel to recalculate when F5 changes). ie. `=BigIf('Sheet1'!$F$5)`

```
Function BigIF(oRng As Range) As Variant
    Dim oWS As Worksheet, oRngRef As Range
    Dim lRowOffset As Long, lColOffset As Long, sID As String

    Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set oRngRef = oWS.Range("B3") ' Offset Reference
    sID = oRng.Text ' Sheet1!F5 value
    ' ROW OFFSET: Sheet2!$B$1 value
    lRowOffset = CLng(oWS.Range("B1").Value)
    ' COLUMN OFFSET: based on sID
    Select Case sID
        Case "AOM":         lColOffset = 1
        Case "Mid Adj":     lColOffset = 6
        '... Other Cases
        Case Else:          lColOffset = 0
    End Select
    BigIF = oRngRef.Offset(lRowOffset, lColOffset)
    Set oRngRef = Nothing
    Set oWS = Nothing
End Function
```

Of cause you can also use the Worksheet_Change event method, but more code.